# What does " records[rec] = (rec in records) ? records[rec] : func(rec) " command in awk mean?

Tags: awk

Can anyone tell me what this expression means in awk?

```c
records[rec] = (rec in records) ? records[rec] : func(rec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rec in records
```

evaluates to a true value if `rec` is already used [as an index in the associative array `records`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html#index-in-operator), false otherwise.

```
(rec in records) ? records[rec] : func(rec)
```

uses [the ternary operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html), and evaluates to `records[rec]` ([the value associated with `rec` in `records`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html)) if there is such a value, or the result of `func(rec)` otherwise.

```
records[rec] = (rec in records) ? records[rec] : func(rec)
```

stores the result in `records[rec]`.

This is the equivalent of

```
if (!(rec in records)) records[rec] = func(rec)
```

but with no assignment if the value is already present; *i.e.*, store the result of `func(rec)` in `records[rec]` if the `rec` index isn’t present in `records`.

Comment: The last version at least avoids the unnecessary assignment. I have a vague memory that the OP version fails in some ancient version of Awk (maybe SunOs 1 or AIX 3): the first mention of `records[rec] =` created the array element *before* it evaluated `rec in records`.